# jQuery slider. Margin animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple slider. The problem in the margin animation, when the slider element reaches the last position, it should show the first element, the behavior of the slider scrolls all the elements to the beginning through the previous elements. I need after the last element of the slider slide to have normal animation to number 1, just like when switching from previus element. Codepen link https://codepen.io/donchak1610/pen/BZbEXp?editors=1010 . Only second button on bottom.

```
 let buttonPrev = $('#button-prev');
let buttonNext = $('#button-next');
let screenImage = $('#screen-image');
let counter = 1;
let controlHeight = $('.slider-control__img').height();
let controlWrapper;

buttonNext.click(function () {
console.log(counter);
if (counter < 4) {
  controlWrapper = $(this).find('.slider-control__wrapper');
  controlWrapper.css('margin-top', '-='+controlHeight+'px');
  counter++;
} else {
  counter = 1;

  controlWrapper.css('margin-top', '0px');
 }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

the `controlWrapper` variable is empty.
You should add a selector to it like you did here `controlWrapper = $(this).find('.slider-control__wrapper');`.

```
else {
    counter = 1;
    controlWrapper = $(this).find('.slider-control__wrapper');
    controlWrapper.css('margin-top', '0px');
}
```